# How do I get the MAC-address of the user of my site (my server)

Tags: php, javascript, perl, unix, cgi

How do I get the Mac address of the user of my site (server). Welcome any tools, methods and techniques, all language. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is: you can't. Even assuming you could pull a MAC address from the request, the user goes through many network devices before hitting your site so how would you know which of these the MAC address came from?

Comment: By that logic, one wouldn't know the originating IP address either, yet one does (proxies aside). What you gave is not the reason the address is not available.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your site is on the Internet (as opposed to a LAN), you can't.

That information is not exposed to client side JavaScript and isn't routed over the Internet.

Comment: Really? I'm coming from the internet, and you know my MAC address is `d4:be:d9:92:9e:4d`

Comment: @ikegami - only because you told me. There is no way I could have made your machine pass that information to me without your manual intervention.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your visitors come over the internet and not simply the local network: **You don't.**
It is not part of the underlying protocol to transport that information more than a hop on the network.

Comment: Really? I'm coming from the internet, and you know my MAC address is `d4:be:d9:92:9e:4d`

Comment: @ikegami And *how* do I know that?

Comment: Well sure, if you explicitly send this information... But it is not part of any existing protocol and requires customization of the client, which I do not think the OP wants. (Arguably hard to tell with the terse question, just guessing from experience here.)

Answer (score 0):

By having the client send you the machine's MAC addresses to you. You'd have to execute some code on the client capable of collecting that information, and have it include that data in the communications with the server.

For example, you could have linux clients run `/sbin/ifconfig` and collect the MAC addresses from the output. You didn't specify what protocol you are using to communicate, so I can't offer advice on how to send the data once you've collected it.

Why do you want that? The machine might not even have any MAC addresses, or it might have several.